# Form shows again after maximizing app even though it was hidden previously with form.hide;

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

The sequence is this:

I start my application at one form. After pressing a button, I call another form and hide the first one. After pressing another button, I execute `Application.Minimize()`.
And then, when I maximize the application by pressing the app icon, the first form is shown again.

Does maximizing show all existing forms again?

Comment: I cannot reproduce. Form2 becomes visible when app icon is hit, Form1 remains hidden. It might depend on OS. I have Win 10. Which OS do you have?

Comment: Preferably provide your forms PAS and DFM codes - that way we can eliminate design settings or bad code to be the culprit. Hopefully your translation service gets this text right.

Comment: If the first form is your main form, you may need to set `application.mainForm := secondForm` after you hide the first form.

Comment: @IVOGELOV In Delphi applications you can't change the `MainForm` at runtime. Because of that `MainForm` property is a read-only property.

Comment: Do both of your forms create their own taskbar icons? If not then it is possible that the taksbar icon belong to your main form and thus clicking on it actually sends `WM_SHOWWINDOW` to your main form instead to your second form as you might expect. Your second form needs to have its own taskbar icon in order to receive `WM_SHOWWINDOW` message directly.

Comment: @SilverWarior that's exactly what was happening, but as I don't want to have two different taskbar icons and it seems I can't hide the one from the main form; what I did was turning the "second form" into the main form, by launching formcreate first for that form